# is there a way to delete users from inside a flutter app from a firebase database

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

so I made an app that acts as an admin where the admin can add users, these users can then log into their account using the credentials(email and password set by the admin) the admin just assigned to them.

adding the user is working but not in the way it is intended to, but I couldn't find anything that will help me delete the user from the list(meaning deleting the user data as well as their respective credentials).
the image here shows a list of the users added by the admin from the admin app I want a function that will allow me to delete user data as well as the credentials from the firebase database.

and if possible when the delete function is found I would love to get the function to add users with their credentials, because while my function works (it adds the users' credentials to the firebase and add the user data to the list and it doesn't redirect me to the account I just added)
`onPressed:() async{DocumentSnapshot data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("user").doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).get(); print(data.get("name"))}` returned the user I just added ex the user I just added using the admin account, even tho I'm logged into the admin account .

i know my English is messed up and I probably haven't explained this the right way but please for those willing to help feel free to ask any question u need

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you adding the users?  That shouldn't be possible using the Flutter SDK for Firebase Auth.  It requires use of the Admin SDK on a backend service that you would invoke using some API call from your app.   Deleting a user requires the same work.

Comment: thanks u for ur response here is my discord Chojii#4050 if u have just some free time id like to understand what languages do i need to learn how to integrate admin sdk into my app

Answer (score 0):

to delete a user from firebase, you can use this

```
Future<User> _getFirebaseUser() async {
    return FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  }


var user = await _getFirebaseUser();

    await user.delete();
```

to delete user data you can use:

```
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).delete();
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but this would delete the user i'm currently logged into and i don't want that i want to delete the user data as well as auth credentials of a specific user from the list in the first image

Comment: hi i edited my answer  please check FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).delete();
if you are using admin panel and want admin to remove specific user so you will need to store uid in your db so you can delete user/user data

Comment: hello, if u have discord can you please contact me here is my discord Chojii#4050 I'd like to know more abt this I'm fairly new to flutter, and id like to know which languages should I learn to successfully do this again I'm grateful thanks in advance.